# Record iPhone Screen and audio simultaneoulsy with AssetWriter API

Tags: iphone, video, audio, screen, record

I am stuck to have a feature of recording screen for iPhone.
I am able to **record screen** and creating a video using **AssetWriter** API, but haven't found a solution to **record audio simultaneously**.

There is **AVAssetExportSession** API to impose audio, but this is not the solution for me because my problem is, in my application is similar to talking Tom Application where different sound effects are to be played with character speaking whatever you speak in a different pitch.

I thought solution is to listen the output audio of device and then imposing it to video recorded by using **AVAssetExportSession** API.

But can't figure out how to record output audio of device or iPhone.

Any suggestions??

Thanks,

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this. I am having the same Question. If you have some solution do reply my post @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367717/create-an-application-that-creates-a-video-from-iphone-screen-and-add-audio-from